# Haproxy redirect internal domain to external with ssl - 503

Tags: proxy, ssl, haproxy

I have a `haproxy` lb which is redirecting traffic from `myexternaldomain.com` to `myinternaldomain.com` with an ssl as below:

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 info
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
        debug
        maxconn 2048

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  http-server-close
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 25000
        timeout client  250000
        timeout server  250000


frontend https
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs
        acl mydomain_acl hdr_beg(host) -i myexternaldomain.com

        option forwardfor
        redirect scheme https code 301 if registry_acl !{ ssl_fc }
        use_backend mydomain if mydomain_acl
        default_backend k8s_ingress_http

frontend mydomain_out
        bind 10.200.0.2:35100 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/myexternaldomain.com.pem
        mode http
        option accept-invalid-http-request
        default_backend mydomain

backend k8s_ingress_http
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        server anotherserver server.com:32080 check

backend mydomain
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        server mydomain myinternaldomain.com:443 check ssl verify none
```

With this config, I have been able to redirect traffic to `myinternaldomain.com` via `myexternaldomain.com:35100` from within a cluster of isolated containers. However early this week, this started returning 503 errors:

```
$ curl -v "https://myexternaldomain.com:35100/"
*   Trying 10.200.0.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to myexternaldomain.com (10.200.0.2) port 35100 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=myexternaldomain.com
*  start date: May  8 13:45:29 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  6 13:45:29 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "myexternaldomain.com" matched cert's "myexternaldomain.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: myexternaldomain.com:35100
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
<
<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Same error trying from haproxy itself:

```
# curl --insecure https://10.200.0.2:35100
<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>
```

Haproxy itself remains able to reach `myinternaldomain.com` fine however:

```
# curl  myinternaldomain.com
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>some title here</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=/">
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

And as you can see from the first curl, the ssl on `myexternaldomain.com` remains valid.

There have been no changes to both domains or the endpoint of `myinternaldomain.com` for it to cause this. So right now, I'm a bit clueless to be honest!

So far, I've tried removing the SSL to just use plain http, to no avail (same 503 error).. Specified IP addresses that will be making calls to haproxy for the backend.. logs in `/var/log/haproxy*` don't show anything but the haproxy service starting/stopping.

Apologies for the semi-vague question, but is there anything obvious I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the external domain I was trying to get to had recently been updated to only accept headers coming from the correct domain name.

haproxy seems unable to modify headers over https (understandably), so I have had to go with a tunnel method instead.